# Implement LRS With Tin Can API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tin-can-api

I have to create a project in iPhone which uses the Tin Can API. The Tin Can API is an advanced distributed learning process.

I have no idea about where to start in Objective-C.

I have read the site http://tincanapi.com.

For implementation, I have some basic questions:

1. How and to create my own LRS?
2. How Tin Can API can communicate with my own LRS and LMS with ASIHTTPRequest programatically?

Comment: FYI `ASIHTTPRequest` is no longer being developed. The person who wrote it recommends against using it. Use something like `AFNetworking` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to TinCanAPI at play here. I'm suspecting you only need to handle one of them on iPhone. One part is the client-side that *sends* the statement date to the second part (the LRS server-side). It would be very odd to create the LRS server part on an iOS device, so I'm going with the thought that you need to *send* TinCan statements from an iOS device to an existing LRS.

An LRS accepts statement data via a REST interface and this data can be POSTed using a standard NSURLConnection or using AFNetworking. There are a couple of options for abstracting all those calls with a library one of which is a new OSS version of the basics <strike>appearing very soon from Rustici Software</strike> found here http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanObjC/. <strike>There is no link for it just yet, but feel free to contact me for more details and I'll update this answer with the link as soon as there is a public link.</strike>

For your specific questions:

1.) You can create your own LRS by understanding the spec document and creating the REST endpoints as specified. This is not a trivial undertaking by any means.

2.) Your best bet is to use an SDK or simple GET and PUT/POST statements from AFNetworking to the TCAPI endpoint.

Comment: thanks fo your Info.In ios tin can development not yet started. looking forward with Afnetworking .One more quetion,In client side how do i create statements(noun,verb,object),is it should be automatic genetated by user interaction like for ex sam "Attemped","Experienced",or"Learn" Book.Thanks

Comment: Here is an example of creating statements in javascript. It is very similar in ObjC as an NSDictionary maps to JSON very nicely. http://tincanapi.com/statement-generator/